# Go modules and dependencies with modified vendors

Tags: go, go-modules, govendor

I am trying to convert one Go project to the new modules standard, but I am having trouble with one dependency.

That repository has vendored a library (in this case golang.org/x/net/html) to add some functionality to the library; meaning that it has modified the vendored dependency (added a method to a struct).

So the problem is that after doing `go mod init`, when i execute `go get ./...` the system complains about a call to that added functionality, because it ignores the modified vendor and tries to import the upstream library instead.

Is there any way to let `go mod` know that it should use the vendored dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`replace`](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) directive. Something along the lines of

First

```
cd ./vendor/golang.org/x/net/html
go mod init
```

Then in your root `go.mod`

```
module your/super/module

replace golang.org/x/net/html => ./vendor/golang.org/x/net/html

require golang.org/x/net/html v0.0.0
```

Note that both `require` and `replace` are required.

Comment: Since issue is that the vendor folder is in one of my dependencies, my module depends on a repository that has the vendor in it. So what I had to do, following your tip, is to clone the dependency elsewhere in my hardisk, go to the `vendor/golang.org/x/ne/htmlt` folder and do `go mod init`.

Then the replace section in the root `go.mod` was 

`replace golang.org/x/net/html => ../../path/elsewhere/vendor/golang.org/x/net/html`

And now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After `go1.15` you can build with `-mod=readonly` to avoid imports only from the vendor directory.

example:

`go build -mod=readonly -o ./build/project -ldflags "-s -w" main.go`